# PHRets using POST

Tags: php, curl

I'm using PHRets and trying to return some search results.  Below is the code, which is very basic and should work:

```
include('../include/common.php');
include('../classes/phrets.php');

$rets = new phRETS();

$connect = $rets->connect(RETS_LOGIN_URL, RETS_USERNAME, RETS_PASSWORD);
if($connect){
    $search = $rets->SearchQuery('PROPERTY', 'RES', '((COUNTY=Dallas))', array('LIMIT'=>20));
    print_r($rets->Error());
    echo $rets->TotalRecordsFound($search);
    $rets->Disconnect();

}else{
    $error = $rets->Error();
    print_r($error);
}
```

When I run the page, I receive the following error:

```
Array ( [type] => rets [code] => 20203 [text] => The request limit is too large for a GET. Please use the POST method to submit your search. ) 0
```

I don't see a parameter to force PHRets to send the request as a POST.  Will this require a hack of the class, or am I missing something?

Thanks

EDIT:  I just heard back from the developer.  It's not supported at this time.  Perhaps a less-busier person should clone it and work on that.. :)    Anyway, if anyone has already has modified the code to make this work, let me know, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the latest phRETS version which supports POST method from [here](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/blob/master/phrets.php) and replace with your old phrets.php.

then you need to add an extra line to the script

```
$rets->SetParam('use_post_method', true);
```

Note: By default it will be GET method.

Answer (score 1):

I've published an updated version supporting POST searches available at https://github.com/nathanklick/PHRETS or via composer by adding `"nathanklick/phrets": "1.0.2"` to your composer.json file.